# Crash due to RecyclerView Button setOnClickListener on a Null reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106484/how-to-add-a-button-at-the-end-of-recyclerview) solution as a guide to add a footer button into my RecyclerView (the last ViewHolder item is a button) but i'm getting a null object reference in my Adapter classes' *onBindViewHolder* when I try to set an onClickListener on the button.

I have a feeling the problem is pretty simple, i think i'm just overlooking it after much debugging.

Can you spot what's causing the Button mAddChordButton to be null when I set the on click listener?

**Adapter Class**

```
    public class UserChordsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserChordsAdapter.ChordViewHolder> {

    final private ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener;
    private static int viewHolderCount;
    private int mNumberItems;

    public interface ListItemClickListener {
        void onListItemClick(int clickedItemIndex);
    }


    public UserChordsAdapter(int numberOfItems, ListItemClickListener listener) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public ChordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ...
        View listItem;
        ChordViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (viewType == R.layout.user_chord_list_item) {    //item isn't last in list
            listItem = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, parent, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
            viewHolder = new ChordViewHolder(listItem);
            viewHolder.viewHolderIndex.setText("Chord " + viewHolderCount);
        }
        else{   //inflate "+ Add new" button for last list item
            listItem = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, parent, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
            viewHolder = new ChordViewHolder(listItem);
        }

        viewHolderCount++;
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ChordViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position == mNumberItems){
            holder.mAddChordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){   //ERROR HERE
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //TODO: Add New Chord into RecyclerView
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNumberItems + 1;// +1 is for footer button (add new)
    }

    class ChordViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {

        // Will display which ViewHolder is displaying this data
        TextView viewHolderIndex;
        public Button mAddChordButton;

        /**
         * Constructor for our ViewHolder. Within this constructor, we get a reference to our
         * TextViews and set an onClickListener to listen for clicks. Those will be handled in the
         * onClick method below.
         */
        public ChordViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mAddChordButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_add_new);      //ATTEMPT TO INITIALIZE BUTTON HERE
            viewHolderIndex = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_view_holder_instance);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        /**
         * Called whenever a user clicks on an item in the list.
         * @param v The View that was clicked
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            mOnClickListener.onListItemClick(clickedPosition);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Distinguishes if view is a Chord list item or the last item in the list (add new chord)
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position == mNumberItems) ? R.layout.user_chord_add_new : R.layout.user_chord_list_item;
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
05-24 22:31:26.284 3083-7540/com.example.foo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.example.foo, PID: 3083
                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at com.example.foo.UserChordsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserChordsAdapter.java:68)
                                                                     at com.example.foo.UserChordsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserChordsAdapter.java:15)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6067)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6100)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5282)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5158)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2061)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1445)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1408)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:580)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3379)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2906)
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1117)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:642)
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1098)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:642)
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:911)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1358)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Please add the logcat

Comment: Post full Logcat.

Comment: Please have a look on this example https://github.com/vkdinventor/RecycleViewLoadMore

Comment: Did you mean to use `ChordViewHolder` in both the if and else statements? In other words, what's the true purpose of the if else other than the setText?

Comment: You are missing button with id button_add_new in any layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes. The if else is just setting text if the current listItem isn't the last element, which is the button. I'll post logcat tonight, but it's pretty unremarkable.

Comment: @user12345 No, there is a layout containing just this button with that id name.

Comment: @cricket_007 Posted Logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I simply inflated the wrong layout in onCreateViewHolder. After declaring the correct layout ID for the footer view and inflating that in my else statement it worked.

The correct code is:

```
@Override
    public ChordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.user_chord_list_item;
        int layoutIdForFooterItem = R.layout.user_chord_add_new; //SOLUTION
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View listItem;
        ChordViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (viewType == R.layout.user_chord_list_item) {    //inflate normal list item
            listItem = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, parent, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
            viewHolder = new ChordViewHolder(listItem);
            viewHolder.viewHolderIndex.setText("Chord " + viewHolderCount);
        }
        else{   //inflate "+ Add new" button for last list item
            listItem = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForFooterItem, parent, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
            viewHolder = new ChordViewHolder(listItem);
        }

        viewHolderCount++;
        return viewHolder;
    }
```