# How to add button in recyclerview GridView Android Studio

Tags: java, android

[image]This layout is a model, not production. I'm a beginner and study it myself. It's difficult to understand. What should the layout be?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106484/how-to-add-a-button-at-the-end-of-recyclerview) will work for you.

Comment: You need to create a custom `RecyclerView/GridView` with a custom adapter and custom item layout to each element in your `gridView/recyclerView`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a button at the end of RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106484/how-to-add-a-button-at-the-end-of-recyclerview)

Comment: Thank you they vey much

Comment: How is your question related to Cloud Firestore? Please don't such tags when not needed.

Comment: You have a clip vedio in youtube?

Comment: Excause me. The value is "myItems" don't seen in this link. Explain this please.